# Convert a string into a int

Tags: vb.net

I need some help here, I am currently making a game, but I got stuck somewhere. So, what I want is, if a Labels text is higher then the other labels text, then something will happen, I typed `If Label26.Text > Label24.Text Then Label33.Visible = True` which seems not to work, please, I need some help here, thanks. And yes, the labels text is NUMBERS.

Comment: `Int32.Parse(Label26.Text)` if it's an integer or `Decimal.Parse`/`Double.Parse` if it's a decimal number.

Comment: Do the label value come from somewhere? Maybe you should check the source (which should already be a number) instead of directly checking the label.

Comment: Since _you_ are not a computer but a human you should consider to use meaningful, human readable variable names and not `Label33`.

Comment: Tim Schmelter, thankyou, your solution with Int32.Parse(Label26.Text) worked, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Text` property of a label is a `string`. As far as computers go, you can't do math (using comparison operators like `>` will not return the result you are [expecting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/215yacb6.aspx#Anchor_1)) with strings because they are just a sequence of characters.

Even if the string only contains a number, the computer still sees it as a sequence of characters and not a number (`"5"` is a string literal with the ***character*** 5 in it, while `5` is an ***integer*** that can be used in a mathematic expression).

As some of the other commenters mentioned, you need to cast the `Text` property to an Integer or Double (or some other numeric data type). To do so, you'd want to use `Int32.Parse` to change the strings to integers.

`If Int32.Parse(Label26.Text) > Int32.Parse(Label24.Text) Then Label33.Visible = True`

Comment: Thanks, you really explained it :)

Comment: Although your sentiment is correct, your statement that strings can't be used with comparison operators is wholly incorrect.         `Dim s1 As String = "f"
        Dim s2 As String = "monkey123"

        If s1 > s2 Then Foo()` works fine.

Comment: My mistake @MattWilko, I've re-worded the answer per your correction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *int.tryParse* to check if the content of the variable is a number or not. The output of the *TryParse* is a *boolean*, see the example below:

```
int num1 = 0;
 bool num1_ = false;

num1_ = int.TryParse(txt1.Text.ToString(), out num1);
if (num1_)
{
    // Is a number/integer  
    //Do something
}
else
{
    //Is a string
    //Do something else
}
```